# Woocommerce global product (multisite)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy

I set in wordpress the property multisite and activated woocommerce on my network.
My network is formed by a primary site and a subsite.
I would like to see from the subsite see the products on the primary site, and products, attributes and categories in the admin bar corresponding products.

Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with the [WooCommerce MultiStore plugin](https://woomultistore.com/).

**These are a few of the plugin's main features:**

- Any Product can be replicated across network, making it available to any other store
- A product can have different product description and price for each store.
- Each store can use different language, currency, payment options and all other options that are included in a standard stand alone WooCommerce store.
- Unique Product Stock management for an easy inventory evaluation. The stock synchronization option allows you to synchronize the stock values of the same products across all the stores in the network.
- Product management available at the main product, or possible to update / adjust for any other places
- One main WooCommerce orders panel with all domains store orders
- All product meta data available for other blogs, including content images, product galleries and featured thumbnail.
- Any product type as Simple, Grouped, External or Variation
- Theme customization in the main admin

**From one single WordPress admin panel you can manage as many Woocommerce stores that you want, there are no limits.**

You can read the [plugin documentation here](https://woomultistore.com/documentation/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes @Zakir is right.

There is no way to share product databases, checkout and user accounts in WooCommerce right now.

There are many people looking for this solution, a WooCommerce MultiSite and Multi Store feature is a must.

I was looking for the very exact thing, since I need to create a website that works like Etsy.com or Themeforest.com and this is what I have found so far:

**1. These guys have done some research:**

[WooCommerce Multisite Global Cart](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/woocommerce-multisite-global-cart/)

[WooCommerce Multisite Stores](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-single-shopping-cart-checkout-option-woocommerce-multi-site-stores/)

[WooCommerce Single Cart Multisite](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-single-shopping-cart-across-woocommerce-multisite/)

Since it is really hard to create a fully working WooCommerce MultiSite and global cart plugin (if not impossible) there is the need of a WooCommerce version that is meant to do just that.

I tried to understand with the WooCommerce guys if there is the possibility to have such a feature in WooCommerce in a reasonable amount of time, but looks like this is something that may take ages, since the WooCommerce developers are focusing on other things.

Recently I have found: [Link removed, site no longer exists]

**2. WooMU MultiSite WooCommerce Fork**

This is an Open Source project that aims to do just that, a Multi Site and MultiStore version of WooCommerce. Looks promising, since they want to keep compatibility with future releases of WooCommerce but focusing on MultiSite and Multi Store features.

I am contributing to this project right now. They are still in Alpha stage and looking for ideas and to grow the community.

The Beta launch is set for 31 Dec 2015.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @russellfeeed Confirmed dead 2017-11-22. No activity on the github page either.

Answer (score 1):

While you can network activate plugins, like WooCommerce and it's extensions, you wouldn't be able to share product databases, checkout, user accounts, etc... across the sites in the network at this time.

For more details please check the official answer here - https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202173667-How-does-woocommerce-function-on-multisite-