# WooCommerce multisite, sharing products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, multisite

I'm trying to combine a set of existing WooCommerce installs into one, to help running them all a lot easier.

In the current set up, there is:

- companysite.co.uk -> which sells all products
- productfamilya.co.uk -> which sells one subset of products
- productfamilya.org -> which sells the same subset of products
- productfamilyb.co.uk -> which sells a different subset of products

It looks like the current set up of multistore on woocommerce was not built for this purpose. It is currently designed for an "Etsy type" shop, with multiple vendors, each with their own shop, with its own products. I want a **single vendor**, with **multiple shops**, selling from a **shared set of products**.

In the very near future, there is going to be a need for international sites. These would be copies of the other sites, in different languages, with different domains. So, ideally, whatever solution I arrive at, would allow for this.

From what I have found so far, a multisite WordPress install, with WooCommerce, and one of the following plugins seems like the best idea:

- woomultistore
- woocommerce-multisite-product-sync
- threewp-broadcast

At this point, I really feel like I have overcomplicated this, and I thought this would be a much more common requirement. Have I missed, or misunderstood, a part of woocommerce or multisite that would let me do this? Is this the "right way" to do this?

Most of my research was in threads that ended with no real answer, so if nothing else, I wanted to consolidate what I've found, in case anyone else is trying this!

Comment: Similar threads/issues to help understand my problem or solve you own:

 =>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431928/wordpress-multisite-woocommerce    
 -=>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745555/woocommerce-global-product-multisite/40023541
 - https://www.wcvendors.com/help/topic/woomu-forking-wc-to-be-natively-multisite/    
 =>   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133618/is-it-possible-to-set-up-multistore-in-woocommerce    
=>   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232201/how-to-share-same-post-to-multiple-site-in-wordpress

Comment: I was wondering if you had found a solution to this problem over the past 4 months?

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry Rich! I couldn't find anything I was confident would be stable over Christmas, so I've been stabilising the current sites for the time being instead. I do plan to come back to this next year though, and "woomultistore" looked like the best option from the above, my main hesitation being that I couldn't find any support besides from the contact form on their site. I'd be really interested to hear if you've found any other options or have any suggestions?

Comment: 3 years later I am running in the exact same need! Did you solve?